# Error in Python Code

Tags: python, oop, self

This is My Code

```
 class New_Class:
    def func(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def prnt(self):
        print(self.name)
```

I created an Object like this

```
obj = New_Class
```

Assigned String :

```
obj.func("Aniket")
```

Called  Function :

```
obj.prnt()
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3e8021509a88> in <module>()
----> 1 obj.func("Aniket")

TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: You need to _call_ the constructor for the class: `obj = New_Class()`. Doing `obj = New_Class` assigns `obj` to the _class object_ `New_Class`. And when a method is called directly on a class, Python does not implicitly pass an object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To init an instance as a class, you need to call the class (with brackets "()" ), instead of just referring to it (without brackets).

So the correct code would be

```
class New_Class:
    def func(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def prnt(self):
        print(self.name)

obj = New_Class()   ##### Brackets make a difference
obj.func("Aniket")
obj.prnt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your variable to the class reference instead of instantiating a new object out of the class.

You may add parentheses to do that job for you such as:

```
obj = New_Class()
obj.func("Aniket")
obj.prnt()
```

I think your function will work fine after this change.

:)